# replacing a matching word in a string by a word using r

Tags: r, string

I am trying to replace a string with a word after having found a match.

I have the following words:

```
bigrams = c("technical lead", "project engineer", "head of")
```

and the following string:

```
string = c("technical lead rotatives", "resident project engineer", "head of medicine", "senior project engineer")
```

I would like the answer to be:

```
answer = c("technical lead", "project engineer", "head of", "project engineer")
```

I have tried various things such as:

```
gsub("^(\\w).* project engineer$", " project engineer", string)
```

which only works for a case.  Any help. Sorry I am not very good at working with strings.
thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at `stringr` package, it makes life easier: https://stringr.tidyverse.org/

```
library(stringr)

bigrams = c("technical lead", "project engineer", "head of")
string = c("technical lead rotatives", "resident project engineer", "head of medicine", "senior project engineer")
answer = c("technical lead", "project engineer", "head of", "project engineer")

pattern <- paste(bigrams, collapse = "|")
result <- str_extract(string, pattern)
identical(answer, result)
# TRUE
```

Comment: That is perfect. It works for my bi and tri-grams Thank you so much. I will have  a look at stringer.